# With Linux user namespaces, why can clone() mount /proc, but unshare() cannot?

Tags: mount, proc, namespace, unshare, clone

I am trying to get a non-root user to mount `/proc` in a Linux user namespace.

If I create a namespace via `clone()`, then I can mount `/proc`.

However, if I create a namespace via `unshare()`, then the call to `mount()` fails with `Operation not permitted`.

Why does `mount()` behave differently when the namespace is created with `clone()` as opposed to `unshare()`?

The below code demonstrates the difference.

```
#define   _GNU_SOURCE
#include  <errno.h>
#include  <sched.h>
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <stdlib.h>
#include  <string.h>
#include  <unistd.h>
#include  <sys/syscall.h>
#include  <sys/mount.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include  <sys/stat.h>
#include  <sys/wait.h>
#include  <fcntl.h>


#define STACK_SIZE (1024 * 1024)

static char child_stack[STACK_SIZE];    /* Space for child's stack */


void  try  ( const char * msg, int rv )  {
  printf ( "%-8s  %6d  %s\n", msg, rv, strerror ( rv < 0 ? errno : 0 ) );
}


int  child  ( void * arg )  {
  try(  "mount_1",   mount   (  "PROC", "/proc", "proc", 0, NULL  ));
  try(  "umount_1",  umount  (  "/proc"                           ));
  return  0;
}


int  main  ()  {

  int  clone_flags  =  0;

  clone_flags  |=  CLONE_NEWNET;
  clone_flags  |=  CLONE_NEWNS;
  clone_flags  |=  CLONE_NEWPID;
  clone_flags  |=  CLONE_NEWUSER;

  try(  "clone",    clone    (  child, child_stack + STACK_SIZE,
                                clone_flags | SIGCHLD, NULL       ));
  try(  "wait",     wait     (  NULL                              ));
  try(  "unshare",  unshare  (  clone_flags                       ));
  try(  "mount_2",  mount    (  "PROC", "/proc", "proc", 0, NULL  ));

  return  0;

}
```

Output:

```
clone      31478  Success
mount_1        0  Success
umount_1       0  Success
wait       31478  Success
unshare        0  Success
mount_2       -1  Operation not permitted
```

I am running on Ubuntu 18.04 with kernel `Linux 4.15.0-20-generic`.  I am running the above code as non-root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're still in the "wrong" PID namespace, and that means you don't have permission to mount the procfs instance.

> **CLONE_NEWPID** [...] The calling process is
>                 not moved into the new namespace.  The first child created by
>                 the calling process will have the process ID 1 and will assume
>                 the role of init(1) in the new namespace.
>
> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unshare.2.html

Compare

> **CLONE_NEWPID** [...]
>                 If CLONE_NEWPID is set, then create the process in a new PID
>                 namespace.
>
> http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html

Comment: It certainly appears you are correct.  If I `unshare()` followed by a `fork()`, then the child process can mount `/proc`.  Thanks!